# Fetch works but when I use Axios I get CORS error

Tags: axios, fetch, nuxt.js

So I am using a **Third-party** API called graphhopper API.

First I used fetch() to call the API and it works but when I use the Axios I get a CORS error.

[image]

```
// THIS WORKS OKAY :)
const response = await fetch(`${graphHopperUrl}/optimize?key=${graphHopperApiKey}`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(problem)
})
```

```
// DOESN'T WORK :(
const response = await this.$axios.post(
   `${graphHopperUrl}/optimize?key=${graphHopperApiKey}`,
    problem,
)
```

Comment: your url is `test.localhost`, it should be graphhopper

Comment: I can't do that since im only using it as a 3rd party API, What makes it weird is Fetch works and Axios doesn't

Comment: What's "problem" ?  Would it help to write data: { problem } ?